# ScrollView force unecessary shape redraw

Tags: swiftui

I have a complex shape in a view contained in a scroll view. Each time I scroll the view the shape is drawn making  the application clumsy and unresponsive.

This a simple test code.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = MainViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ....
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                SubView()
                    .stroke()
                    .frame(minWidth: 700)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: Shape {
    
    init() {
        print("init")
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        dprint("drawing")
        
        let newPath =  Path { path in
            for _ in 0..<600 {
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width, y: rect.size.height))
            }
        }
       
        return newPath
    }
}
```

I tried to change the code in order to cache the path:

```
struct SubView: Shape {
    var cachedPath: Path?
    
    init() {
        print("init")
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        dprint("drawing")
        
        if let path = cachedPath {
            dprint("cached path")
            return path
        }
        
        let newPath =  Path { path in
            for _ in 0..<600 {
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width, y: rect.size.height))
            }
        }
       
        cachedPath = newPath // <-- Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
        
        return newPath
    }
}
```

but I get the following error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

How do I avoid the shape to be redrawn each time a scroll it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up integrating a custom UIView using UIViewRepresentable. It is super fast and scrolling the view doesn't re-launch the draw(_ rect: CGRect).

Sure it's not a pure SwiftUI solution but it's exactly what I need.